# Snowflake stored procedure - able to return multiple result sets?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Teradata, let's say I have a main macro which calls 2 other macros, each with its own SELECT statement. When I run this main macro, Teradata's user interface creates 2 resultset tabs, with each tab containing the results of each `SELECT` statement.

Can we do the same thing in Snowflake?

My understanding is: "no, this is not possible in Snowflake". This is because a Snowflake stored procedure returns a maximum of 1 value or 1 table. Therefore Snowflake is unable to return multiple 'result sets' in multiple result tabs the way Teradata does.

Comment: No, you can't do this in Snowflake. It doesn't have tabbed result pages so it can't display the results of multiple queries

Comment: But you can use query history down in the query results section to tab through multiple query resultsets in a worksheet.